# Is there any opensource ODBC library for FORTRAN?

Tags: open-source, odbc, fortran

I am looking for a Odbc library for Fortran (gFortran/Win). There was one product available by the name f90SQL but its now discontinued. I don't want write my own API wrapper for Odbc that would take alot of time is there any opensource or even a product that would provide that service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick google came up with several options:

- [ForDBC](http://www.ntxintl.com/fordbc_e.htm)
- [flibs/odbc](http://flibs.sourceforge.net/fodbc.html)
- [windtracer ODBC Intercation](http://www.winteracter.com/subs.htm#odbc)

I don't know if any of these are suitable, but some are open source and you should be able to adapt to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm excavating an old question but it pops up in google search.

It is only flibs/odbc that is free software among those Oded mentioned. It lacks some nice features like column binding and it generally enforces its own API. I took an effort to generate Fortran 2003 C bindings directly from ODBC headers. [fodbc](https://github.com/mlt/fodbc) is far from being complete. But [simple example](https://github.com/mlt/fodbc/wiki/Example) with sqlite3 works for me so far. It looks like tests with MS Access reading and MS Excel writing do well.